# R: CDF with data from arbitrary number of columns

Tags: r

I use following commands to print CDF based on values in two columns in a data frame X.  I want to programmatically extend this to N columns without writing N lines.  Is there any easy way?

```
CDF1 <- apply(as.matrix(quantiles), 1, function(x) { return(quantile(X$col1, x, na.rm=T)) })
CDF2 <- apply(as.matrix(quantiles), 1, function(x) { return(quantile(X$col2, x, na.rm=T)) })
result <- cbind(quantiles, CDF1, CDF2)
result
```

Comment: May be `lapply(X, function(x) apply(quantiles, 1, function(y) quantile(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)))` (not tested without an example data)

Comment: Thanks that works.  Just had to replace lapply with apply, quantiles with as.matrix(quantiles) and specify column 2